# How should I configure Eclipse Java project to extract jar package on every build?

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

I wan to share one of my Java classes form existing Eclipse project with other projects.
I am doing it manually with menu: File -> Export -> Java -> JAR file.

I am dealing with frequent code changes in referenced Java project, therefore, unnecessarily spending time on this step that can me automated. My challenge is how to tie this step to project build step. Any ideas ?

Best

Answer (score 0):

i think you must extract the just the jar and place it in the your eclipse working directory
,it could solve your problem......

Comment: do you know simpler solution ? other API ?

Comment: you can do it in the Android Studio Instead of Eclipse.add the dependencies the gradle will automatically downloads the required jar.